# Issues Logging in Twice After Installing Lightspeed Module

Tags: session, caching, magento, lightspeed

We are having an issue with logging in a second time on our site ever since we installed the lightspeed module.  At first I thought this might have to do with the need for hole punching, but now I'm not sure.
If you try to log into our website the first time, it works well.  However, if you log in a second time, it won't work.  It just remains on the customer/account/login page with no effect.

I tried to test this on my end, and echoed the user's email in the loginPost function in the account controller.  When echoing directly from the controller, it was obvious that the user was being logged in, but upon the redirect to a page on the site, the user was no longer logged in and appeared as a Guest in the Magento backend (where you view online customers).

It appears to me as if the session is being lost after the redirect.  I am not sure if this has anything to do with a switch between https and http as described in the stackoverflow problem here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823994/magento-session-lost-when-switching-to-https-from-http ) where they had also installed lightspeed.  The person there resolved the problem, but did not post the solution.  Their problem wasn't the same as ours, but I was thinking there may be a connection between the two.

Has anyone seen a problem like this before?

Thanks in advance,

Brenda

Comment: I'd encourage people to answer below, but I'd also encourage you to contact Lightspeed support. You paid $500 for the extension, and that should include, at minimum, email support.

Comment: Contact Lightspeed (TinyBrick). They've always been really helpful at answering questions in setting up their software.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I've contacted Lightspeed and they are helpful, but I was wondering if anyone else had input to give or encountered a similar situation.

Comment: Still, it would make a nice contribution to have an answer to this issue on SO.