# How can i set session expiration limit for a particular store view?

Tags: magento, session, cookies, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am new to magento and i am facing the problem with session expiration limit for a particular store.

In my site i have 2 store views, i want to give expiration limit for one of the store and  I googled for this problem and got the solution like

```
 System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management
```

cookie life time value set to 300 seconds and then checked in front end

```
external_no_cache  1                           .stage.mydomain.com /storeview Tue, 02 Sep 2014 08:06:40 GMT 18 
 frontend           g6n80985ubesvrk5a92st2ng45 .stage.mydomain.com /storeview Tue, 02 Sep 2014 07:08:40 GMT 34
 frontend           g6n80985ubesvrk5a92st2ng45 stage.mydomain.com  /               Session                       34
```

and checked the links 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022952/set-session-time-out-limit-for-magento-frontend),
 [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823994/magento-session-lost-when-switching-to-https-from-http)

But my session is not expiring for 300 seconds.

Is it possible to do session expiration for a particular store? and why the cookie is creating 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can set independently per storeview. Go to

```
 System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management
```

Then at top-left, find the Default Configuration Scope dropdown. Select desired storeview, then untick use default and enter the cookie lifetime for that store. Save, repeat for each store.

Comment: I too have a same problem with my cookie and did the samething for my store view  and the cookie settings are shown below and whatever the time i set for my store view is creating the cookie like 
frontend  qwerrtttggki9085768 .mydomain.com /storeview Tue, 08 Aug 2014 07:08:40 GMT 34

And i think there is a cookie having same name below is overriding with the value session